# Polymer.js Web Component Tester Failing to Find Local DOM Element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

Here is my property declaration:

```
  properties: {

    size: {
      type: String,
      value: ''
    }, 

    sizeName: {
      type: String,
      value: ''
    }
  }
```

My CSS:

```
<style>
  :root {
    --width: 20px;
    --height: 20px;
    --border-color: black;
    --font-size: 16px;
  }
  :host {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: var(--height);
    width: var(--width);
  }
  #icon {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: var(--width);
    height: var(--height);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    @apply(--size-icon);
  }
  #icon:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    content: '?';
    text-align: center;
    @apply(--size-icon--before);
  }
  #icon.small:before {content: 's';}
  #icon.medium:before {content: 'm';}
  #icon.large:before {content: 'l';}

  #name {
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    @apply(--size-name);
  }

  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

I have a test fixture as follows:

```
<test-fixture id="hasWrongSize">
  <template>
    <size-icon size="asdf"></size-icon>
  </template>
  <template>
    <size-icon size=""></size-icon>
  </template>
</test-fixture>
```

With a test suite as follows:

```
  suite('when no icon size or incorrect icon size is provided', function() {
    var el;
    setup(function() {
      el = fixture('hasWrongSize');
    });
    test('when the "size" property is incorrect the inner html equals "?"', function(done) {
      flush(function() {
        var domEl = Polymer.dom(el.root).querySelector('#icon:before');
        expect(domEl.innerHTML).to.equal('?');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

The Local DOM of the custom element is as follows:

```
<template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{ !sizeName }}">
    <span id="icon" class$="{{size}}"></span>
  </template>
  <span id="name">{{ sizeName }}</span>
</template>
```

I am trying to get the `:before` pseudo-element with the ID of `#icon` but WCT isn't able to find it and `domEl` in the test suite is equating to `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** *The question was updated to include the complete code of the `test-fixture`, which revealed the root cause.*

As you noted in your own answer:

> 1. I have two template tags so it did not know which element to target.

That alone is the cause of your problem, and the pseudo-element actually had nothing to do with it. You'll find that if you remove one of the templates from the `test-fixture`, your original code would've worked (and would've been cleaner than what you have now IMO).

The `test-fixture` should only contain *one* `template` with a fixed state of your custom element as a baseline (the most common denominator) for your tests. In this case, that baseline is a single `size-icon`, but it seems you're adding a `template` for each possible test case, but that setup should really occur in the test script like this:

```
<test-fixture id="basic">
  <template>
    <size-icon></size-icon>
  </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
  suite('size-icon', function() {
    var el;

    setup(function() {
      el = fixture('basic');
    });

    function expectIconEquals(done, contents) {
      flush(function() {
        var domEl = Polymer.dom(el.root).querySelector('#icon');
        expect(domEl.innerHTML).to.equal(contents);
        done();
      });
    }

    test('when the "size" property is empty, the inner html equals "?"', function(done) {
      el.size = "";
      expectIconEquals(done, '?');
    });

    test('when the "size" property is invalid, the inner html equals "?"', function(done) {
      el.size = "asdf";
      expectIconEquals(done, '?');
    });

    test('when the "size" property is valid, the inner html equals "<some valid content>"', function(done) {
      el.size = "12%";
      expectIconEquals(done, '<some valid content>');
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

**Answer to original question:**

In your code, the `span#icon` element is only stamped when `sizeName` is not `undefined` and is empty. The binding evaluation is similar to [that of computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#dependent-properties) (even though that's not explicitly stated for non-computed bindings):

> The computing function **is not called until all dependent properties are defined** (`!=undefined`). So each dependent properties should have a default value defined in properties (or otherwise be initialized to a non-`undefined` value) to ensure the function value is computed.

To resolve the issue, set `sizeName` to the empty string in your test before flushing the template.

```js
suite('when no icon size or incorrect icon size is provided', function() {
  var el;
  setup(function() {
    el = fixture('hasWrongSize');
  });
  test('when the "size" property is incorrect the inner html equals "?"', function(done) {

    // #icon exists only when sizeName is empty string
    el.sizeName = "";

    flush(function() {
      var domEl = Polymer.dom(el.root).querySelector('#icon');
      expect(domEl).to.not.be.null;
      expect(domEl.innerHTML).to.equal('?');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you could initialize `sizeName` inside your `dom-module`:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'size-icon',
  properties: {
    sizeName: {
      type: String,
      value: function() { return ""; }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't specific enough in my code. I will update it with my property declarations. I was already setting a default value equal to an empty string. However, the error comes on the domEl variable. It is equating to Null.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the problem. I've tried Chrome 53 & 51, Firefox 46.0.1, Safari 9.1 on OS X El Capitan. What's your test environment? And which browsers are failing?

Comment: I discovered the solution to my problem. I did not provide you with a clear enough code sample. I made the edits and posted the solution I discovered.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I was using a ':before' element to fill the content of the `#icon` span. When trying to select it I ran into two issues:

1. I have two template tags so it did not know which element to target.
2. I was incorrectly selecting a pseudo-element.

Here is the code I used to properly select and test the `content` attribute of the pseudo-element.

```
  var getBeforeText = function(el) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(
      getIcon(el), ':before'
    ).getPropertyValue('content').replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "");
  };

  var getIcon = function(el) {
    return Polymer.dom(el.root).querySelector('#icon');
  };

  suite('when no icon size or incorrect icon size is provided', function() {
    var el;
    setup(function() {
      el = fixture('hasWrongSize');
    });
    test('when the "size" property is incorrect the inner html equals "?"', function(done) {
      flush(function() {
        expect(getBeforeText(el)).to.equal('?');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Pseudo-elements are not directly selectable with plain JS because they are not part of the DOM.

Comment: The root cause is that `test-fixture` does not handle multiple templates, and the pseudo-element actually has nothing to do with it. Your original code would've worked if you set up `test-fixture` with only one template.

Comment: Once I had solved the test-fixture issue which was causing `el` to return null I still couldn't get the current text-content of the element. It was returning `''`. After poking around I discovered that the pseudo-element isn't targetable with vanilla JS as a node.